# Angularjs - How can i show my Json that the element retrieve from 2 array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to show the value of my Json element,

"Baru20151","Lama20151","Baru20152","Lama20152", 
but i have no idea how to.

The element is retrieve from 2 array,
in "Baru20151" elements, "20151" is retrieved from "isimasa" array in my Json file.

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl"> 
 <h4 style="text-align:center">REGISTRASI MAHASISWA PENDAS</h4>
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
 <tr>
  <td ng-repeat-start="Isimasa in myDataIsimasa" align="center">Baru</td>
  <td  align="center">Lama</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="Pendas in DataPendas" >
  <td ng-repeat-start="Isimasa in DataIsimasa" align="center">{{Pendas.Baru{{Isimasa.masa}}}}</td>
  <td  align="center">{{Pendas.Lama{{Isimasa.masa}}}}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('RegistrationCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("json.json").then(function (response) {
  $scope.DataPendas = response.data.pendas;
  $scope.DataIsimasa = response.data.isimasa;
  $scope.Data = response.data;
});
});
</script>
```

Json :

```
{"name":"ACEH",

"isimasa":[{"masa":"20151"},{"masa":"20152"}],

"column":9,

"pendas":[

{"kode":"121","prodiname":"PGPAUD", "Baru20151":22,"Lama20151":0,
"Baru20152":22,"Lama20152":20}

]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..
Controller:

```
        <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('RegistrationCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("json.json").then(function (response) {
      $scope.DataPendas = response.data.pendas;
      //console.log($scope.DataPendas);

      $scope.DataIsimasa = response.data.isimasa;
      var isimasa = $scope.DataIsimasa;

      console.log(isimasa);
      $scope.Data = response.data;
      $scope.constructJson = constructJson;

       function constructJson(theKey, jsonKey, jsonObj){
           console.log(theKey, jsonKey);

           var newKey = theKey + jsonKey;
           var newValue = jsonObj[newKey];
           console.log(newValue);
           return newValue;

      }
    });
    });

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl">
```

REGISTRASI MAHASISWA PENDAS

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

    <tr ng-repeat-start="Isimasa in DataIsimasa">
       <td>{{Isimasa.masa}}        
       <div  ng-repeat="Pendas in DataPendas">        
         Baru{{Isimasa.masa}} : {{ constructJson("Baru",Isimasa.masa, Pendas ) }}<br/>
         Lama{{Isimasa.masa}} : {{ constructJson("Lama",Isimasa.masa, Pendas ) }}
        </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat-end>
   </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Glad to help... Please accept the answer... Thanks.